# Android:: how Contact app is connected with Contact provider

Tags: android

I have separated Android Contact app and Contact Provider. Both are installed perfectly in phone. 
When i create a contact with my contact app, this contact is not using my contact provider; it is using android default contact provider, and db file is created in the following location i.e /data/data/com.android.provider.contact/database/contacts2.db.
I want my contact app using my contact provider so that contact.db is saved in the following location i.e /data/data/com.android.xyz.provider.contact/database/contacts2.db.
Where do I need to change in my contact app so that it will use my contact provider ?

Comment: Well depends how you create your contact in your contact app. If you use the default Android mechanism it is quite logical it will be saved in the Android ContentProvider.

Comment: you cannot change, one way could be disable the default android content provider and in your provider define android:authorities as "contacts;com.android.contacts" , but i doubt it will work.

Comment: @RvdK I have used default Android mechanism, because I used the whole code base of Android 4.0.3 Contact and Contact Provider.                     Yes, I agreed with you that I will be default location. But in my phone I have also installed Contact Provider which I have separated and built, its name is com.android.xyz.provider.contacts. So Now what change I need to do in my contact codebase so that it will start using my Contact Provide application? please help

Comment: @nandeesh: In my Contact Provider it is already defined "xyz.contacts;com.android.xyz.contacts" now I do i disable default Contact Provider?

Comment: There should an entry in the Contact code base where I need to mentioned the Contact Provider's name? Is not it? Or any where in the android codebase?

Comment: if you are using xyz.contacts, it will not work. Contacts app will check for content://contacts uri

Comment: @nandeesh: I have disabled default Contact Provider i.e. com.android.providers.contacts. Then installed my provider i.e. com.android.xyz.providers.contacts and this is installed successfully. Then I tried to install my contact i.e. com.android.xyz.contacts , but is the throwing error that "Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts".

Comment: also I have tried another way as u suggested by changing content URI in GroupEditorFragment.java and GroupEditorFragment.java file.final Uri legacyContentUri = Uri.parse("content://lexperts.contacts/people"); and final Uri legacyContentUri = Uri.parse("content://lexperts.contacts/groups"); correspondingly.but still contacts2.db is not created in my provider location.

Comment: I observed that in ContactSaveService.java file in saveContact() rawContactUri is getting from RawContacts.CONTENT_URI so i changed this to "content://com.android.lexperts.contacts/raw_contacts" and now all files(contacts2.db)folders are created inside my provider. But it crashes sometimes.

Comment: you should not have authorities with xyz, you need to define same as contacts

Comment: did not get your point, my Contact is same as android default contact app, I have just rename it with com.android.xyz.contacts so that both of them can be installed simultaneously. Can you please explain your point.